# Dominated positive operator

Tags: functional-analysis

I want that if $H$ Hilbert space where $A$, $B$ are positive operators on $H$ Hilbert space, $0 \leq (Ax|x) \leq (Bx | x)$ $\forall x$, does this mean $(A^2x|x) \leq (B^2x|x)$?

Thank you

Comment: You said that the operators were positive in the title, but not in the body of the question.  In the future, repeat details like this in the body of the question.

Comment: sorry, I thought $A$ positive iff $0 \leq (Ax | x)$ $\forall x$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Read my comment, see the change I made to your question.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom The OP's original statement included that $(Bx|x)\ge(Ax|x)\ge0$, so certainly $A$ and $B$ are positive.

Comment: @Jason only over complex Hilbert spaces

Answer (score 6):

Consider $H = \mathbf K^2$ and the operators 
$$ A = \def\p#1#2#3#4{\begin{pmatrix} #1 & #2 \\ #3 & #4 \end{pmatrix}}\p 1111, \quad B = \p 2111 $$
Then 
\begin{align*}
  \def\<#1>{\left<#1\right>}\<Ax,x> &= |x_1 + x_2|^2\\
   \<Bx,x> &= (2x_1 + x_2)\bar x_1 + (x_1 + x_2)\bar x_2\\
           &= |x_1|^2 + |x_1 + x_2|^2
\end{align*}
Hence $0 \le A \le B$. Taking squares, we have 
$$ A^2 = \p 2222, \qquad B^2 = \p 5332 $$
Hence, 
$$ B^2 - A^2 = \p 3110 $$
Now 
$$ (B^2 - A^2)\binom{1}{-3} = \binom{0}{1} $$
And hence $\<(B^2 - A^2)\binom{1}{-3},\binom{1}{-3}> < 0$, so $A^2\not\le B^2$.